# Visual Studio Cuda Debugger (Nsight) does not show Pointers in Kernel-Parameter structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, nsight

### Objective:

I am developing a scientific CUDA application, where I have several fields of data on the GPU. I develope in Visual Studio 15 and use the NVIDIAs Nsight 5.4 for debugging the GPU Code. I would like to be able to set breakpoints in the kernels and inspect the memory. I pass the device data pointers to the kernels via a structure holding the pointers.

### What does work:

- I can break the code in the kernel.
- I can inspect local variables.
- I can inspect the device memory, if I got the pointer.
- I can print the pointers to the console.
- When I pass the device pointers directly (not as a struct) I can also inspect them.

### What does not work:

- I cannot inspect the pointers inside the structure!

This screenshot shows my Visual Studio with the described problem.

[image: Nsight debug problem]

### Minimal working example:

```cpp
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

struct Param {
    int* a;
    int* b;
};

__global__ void kernel(Param param)
{
    *param.a =  5;
    *param.b = -5;
    printf("a: %p, b: %p\n", param.a, param.b);
}

int main()
{
    Param param;

    cudaMalloc( &param.a, sizeof(int) );
    cudaMalloc( &param.b, sizeof(int) );

    kernel<<<1,1>>>(param);

    return 0;
}
```

I would be glad for all help. Maybe you can tryout if the problem does also appear on other configurations!

My Configuration:

- Win 10, 64 bit
- Visual Studio 15
- Nsight 5.4
- GeForce GTX 1080, Driver 385.41
- Cuda 8.0

Comment: Surely that is just a scope issue? You have a break or observation point at the end of a trivial global function. It is likely that the contents have just fallen out of scope. The GPU isn't running your kernel code, it is running machine code which the debugger has to try and map back to your kernel code. In some cases that can fail. This looks to be one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. About the scope: I also tried breaking the kernel at lines 14, 15 and 16 (in the screenshot). The adresses in the Locals window remain unchanged.

Comment: Again, they might not exist at all in the actual device code in such a trivial example. The GPU toolchain is *very* aggressive with optimization and register allocation.

Comment: Ah, I guess I know what you mean. Hm, too bad... Thank you anyway!

Comment: I had a similar problem, and using @talonmies' second suggestion, verified that optimization was the issue. I made the variables in question visible in the debugger by copying them to global device memory.